# Trimming a mustache during sefira

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, hair

Is it permitted to trim a mustache during sefira if it is not bothering the person in any way with regards to eating but is bothering him in other ways?

Comment: Why would you think he can or can't? What ways can it bother him besides eating? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I always had this question. In the Gemara when talking about the issur of shaving almost the Gemara says is that trimming of the mustache is permitted. All of a sudden the poskim qualify it that it's only permitted when it disrupts eating.

Comment: Are you Sephardic or Ashkenazic? The halakhot can be different in this regard

Comment: I would really love an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue8.pdf) which seems to be a comprehensive summary (I know that's an oxymoron, but you can read the article, anyway ;-). In it, you'll find many cross-refs.

The only permissions to shave are if it interferes with eating, as you mentioned, health reasons, and certain simchot where you are a "direct participant" e.g. your son is having a brit, you're a chatan, etc. You can't trim your mustache if your shidduch "date" will find your mustache ugly. (IMO, if that's a criterion for the date to break a shidduch, consider yourself lucky.) There is no mention regarding other "bothersome" permissibility.